# Is there an equivalent to iOS "Reset Home Screen Layout" on the Nexus 7?

Tags: launcher, nexus-7

On iOS, "Reset Home Screen Layout" auto-arranges your application icons.  Is there an equivalent for this on my Nexus 7 Android tablet?  Right now my icons across several screens.

Comment: Are you asking about re-arranging the home screen icons, or resetting the home screen's items to default settings?

Comment: @Chahk I would like to know how to reset the home screen's layout to default settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to **Settings**->**Apps**, swipe to **All**, scroll and press **Launcher**, then select **Clear data**.

Your home screen is as good as new :)

UPDATE: As suggested by [Chahk](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/31969/is-there-an-equivalent-to-ios-reset-home-screen-layout-on-the-nexus-7/31975#comment41415_31975) below, a good way to avoid cluttering your homescreen is by going to the **Play Store** then going to **Menu** -> **Settings** and un-checking the **Auto-add widgets** option.

Comment: Worth adding that you can disable auto-creating of shortcuts for newly installed apps by opening Play Store then going to Menu --> Settings and un-checking the `Auto-add widgets` option.

Comment: @rnh16 I would never have known to do this but it does work as a "factory reset" of the home screen.

Comment: Frank, glad I could help :) - @Chahk, added, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

On newer devices/OS versions (i.e. Nexus 5X), try going into Google App instead of Launcher, select Storage, Manage Space, CLEAR LAUNCHER DATA.